# How can I insert text from a file into a specific column/row of another text file?

Tags: bash, sed

What would be the easiest to accomplish the following?

Text file 1:

```
survey:
product:
epsg:
crstxt:
zunit:
surfaceunit:
```

Text file 2:

```
product name 1
```

Output:

```
survey:
product: product name 1 
epsg:
crstxt:
zunit:
surfaceunit:
```

Comment: Linux and batch file? Are you sure?

Comment: What determines which line gets changed? The first word?

Comment: Biffen, I wasn't sure which tags to pick. Only the "product:" line will be changed. The rest of text file 1( survey, epsg, crstxt, etc) will remain the same. I'm trying to expand on my question as I research this more. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: Don't choose tags if you don't know that they're correct. So the task is to change a line from `product:` to the same with some text appended? Fairly easy with sed. Which language do you use? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using bash. I tried sed and couldn't get the product name inserted in the right column but I finally figured it out! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^product:/& '"$(< file2)"'/' file1
```

or with two seds and bash's [Process Substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35):

```
sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|^product:|\& &|/' file2) file1
```

Output:

```
survey:
product: product name 1
epsg:
crstxt:
zunit:
surfaceunit:
```

file2 must not contain special characters (e.g. slash, \1 or &)!

Comment: Thanks for your help Cyrus. I was struggling to get the product name in the right column. This helped!!

Comment: Cyrus, would it be possible to insert a product name into multiple "Text file 1" files? I would have one text file with 15 product names and one text file with the contents of "Text file 1". I'm thinking some scripting would be required?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -i -f <(sed 's/.*/s|^product:|\& &|/' file2) file1 file3 file4 file5` This edits your file1 file3 file4 file5 "in place".

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! What if I have five "Text file 2" files with unique product names that need to be inserted into separate "Text file 1" files. Would it be a matter of modifying that GNU sed command?

Comment: This is beyond the scope. Please start a new question. Thank you.